# What movie has a scene near the end where a guy gets covered by newspapers blown by the wind, then disappears?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I saw this movie on TV, cable, or Cinemax, at least 10 years ago, maybe 20.  I don't think it was sci-fi, but maybe involved "magic" of some kind, and was set in a large city.  (NYC or Chicago perhaps?)  I can't recall anything helpful like cast members or plot, only one scene, near the end, sticks in my mind:

One of the "villians" is walking on a sidewalk.  A freak windstorm suddenly kicks up, blowing lots of dust and discarded newspapers around.  Passers-by are ducking into doorways and such, to get out of the wind and flying debris.

Wind-blown newspaper begins adhering to this guy, despite his efforts to remove it, and eventually builds up a newspaper coating on him so thick that he's completely covered, staggering around, and eventually unable to walk.  He falls to the sidewalk and after a while, stops struggling.

The newspapers then start separating from the mass and blowing away.  When all the papers have blown away, we see only empty sidewalk - the guy has disappeared.

Anyone remember this?

Comment: THANK YOU. This scene has been stuck in my brain for nearly 30 years, since I first saw this on tv in 1988 at the age of five. For so long I thought it must have been an old episode of Dr. Who or something. Very much appreciate that someone asked and even more that someone answered!

Answer (score 34):

That’s [Brazil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_%281985_film%29), by Terry Gilliam.

The papers are not newspaper; they are the protagonist Sam Lowry's paperwork. Sam Lowry uses a flexible pipe to connect his paperwork in tube directly to his paperwork out tube. Pressure builds up in the pipe and it explodes, scattering the paperwork out of the office building and into the city.

The character getting covered in paper is Tuttle, played by Robert De Niro, who wouldn’t really be described as a villain.

Answer (score 19):

This is Brazil, by Terry Gilliam from 1985.

Comment: Thanks for the clip, Phantom42.  I see that I was somewhat incorrect in my description of the scene, but close enough for you and the other board experts.  I guess I need to go re-watch Brazil.